# loop insider the render's return statement

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to loop inside the render's return method?

I have an object that looks like this:

```
export var Characters = [
    {
        id: 1,
        Name: "Abe",
        HitPointValue: "124",
        StrengthValue: "12",
        IntelligenceValue: "14",
        WisdomValue: "16",
        DexterityValue: "12",
        ConstitutionValue: "10",
        CharismaValue: "17",
        Avatar: require('./images/avatar_1.jpg')
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Name: "Jake",
        HitPointValue: "141",
        StrengthValue: "21",
        IntelligenceValue: "6",
        WisdomValue: "5",
        DexterityValue: "8",
        ConstitutionValue: "20",
        CharismaValue: "10",
        Avatar: require('./images/avatar_2.jpg')
    }
]
```

Instead of writing out each character in the object like this:

```
render() {
        return (
               <View>
                   <View>
                       <Image source={getAvatar(1)} />
                   </View>
                   <View>
                       <Text>
                            Name: { getName(1)
                       </Text>
                   </View>
               </View>

        )
}
```

I was wondering if I could just loop through it?

thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend going through the main React docs - there's a chapter on how to do [exactly this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: If you have a long list, you might want to look into FlatList or a few of the other better performance options for generating lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Array's [`map() method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

e.g.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {Characters.map(character =>
                <View>
                    <Image source={character.avatar}/>
                    <Text>Name: {character.name}</Text>
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    )
}
```